# iptables blocks update for Microsoft Essentials

Tags: firewall, ms-security-essentials

Please advise which ports/destinations shall be opened at the Linux firewall to allow MS Essentials updates for Windows PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with the way MSE works with proxy. To my surprise, it does not simply takes proxy settings from IE, but requires magic command (for Windows 7):

```
netsh winhttp import proxy ie
```

Details [here](http://all-things-pure.blogspot.com/2009/10/microsoft-security-essentials-network.html).

Even though my proxy was set in transparent mode and above command reports that direct connection is used.